# how to cast object to range type of google spreadsheet in javascript

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm studying to do some function in google spreadsheet.

For example
function test (searchvalue, searchrange)
call :  test("found", B3:C5)

the argument searchrange is object, the genic type is range of Spreadsheet Services,
But how can I cast searchrange to Range of google spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you receive a "range" parameter on a custom function, you receive the values of the range directly, not the range itself.

If the parameter is a single cell, you'll receive its value directly. If it's a multi-cell range, you'll receive a matrix of values. Regardless if the multi-range is a single column or row (it's always a matrix of values).

Anyway, I do not recommend that you develop such function, as there's a native spreadsheet function that already does that, the `match` formula. And it is always better to use native formulas over custom functions, you should avoid custom functions, they're slow and difficult to write and use correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I'm writing a function to replace native spreadsheet function workday. Because workday function always regards Saturday and Sunday as Weekend. But in some parts of the world , their weekend maybe is Thursday and Saturday or only Saturday , even no weekend. So I had to do another function to replace native spreadsheet workday function.

Comment: Hi. There is my test file , https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0At-SsQhTQp0udE9yS3hfX19PcWM0LUtOMF9jYnYtTGc#gid=0                                        below is my script, as you comment,I feel it is not good performance , http://forum.maomifadacai.net/?p=241